# How to add a course to an existing user in moodle remotely?

Tags: php, ldap, moodle

I'm using LDAP to create users in [Moodle](http://moodle.org/). However, after creating an user (adding to LDAP and running the sync script) i want to enroll that user to a course. How one does that? :)

Comment: Have you looked into the web services API?

Comment: I've created a proposal for a Stack Exchange website for Moodle users and developers. This question would be a perfect fit for it, rather than for Stack Overflow. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33861/virtual-learning-environments

Comment: There is this [document](http://download.moodle.org/docs/en/how-to_guides/ldap_auth_and_enrolment_set-up.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

If by "remotely" you mean via a remote script, the one option is to use the SOAP webservices module:

- https://github.com/patrickpollet/moodlews
- http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Web_Services:OK_Tech_Web_Services

This module works with Moodle 1.9 and 2.0 and provides access to methods for user creation, course creation, and enrollment along with much else.

I'm currently using this module in a Moodle 1.9 installation as my sole enrollment process (without creating courses via LDAP on login), but there is no reason you couldn't write a script that looks through your course groups and adds any missing users to the matching Moodle courses them by calling the SOAP methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have four options that I know of:

1. [WebServices](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions) using the enrol_manual_enrol_users() function
2. [LDAP enrollment](https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/LDAP_enrolment) requires a lot of set-up work in active directory
3. [External database enrollment](https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/External_database_enrolment)
4. [Flat file enrollment](https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Flat_file) requires ftp access to your server